# "Cannot resolve method" in Java lambda reference

Tags: java, lambda

I am a little confused why I'm getting the error "Cannot resolve method 'getTabOrder'" here.
I have the classes:

```
@Data
public class TabTuple {
   private final String name;
   ...
}
```

and

```
@Data
public class Rule {
   private final String tabName;
   ...
}
```

Then, in another class I have these methods:

```
public class RuleComparator {
   public static void sortRules(List<Rule> rules) {
     rules.sort(Comparator
        .comparingDouble(RuleComparator::getTabOrder)
        .thenComparingInt(RuleComparator::getFieldScopeOrder)
        .thenComparingInt(Rule::getOrder)
     );
   }

   public static double getTabOrder(TabTuple tabTuple) {
     return getTabOrder(tabTuple::getName);
   }

   public static double getTabOrder(Rule rule) {
     return getTabOrder(rule::getTab);
   }
 
   private static double getTabOrder(Supplier<String> tabNameSupplier) {
      var name = tabNameSupplier.get();
      // Ordering implementation
      ...
   }

   private static int getFieldScopeOrder(Rule rule) {
      ...
   }
}
```

I expected the method reference call `.comparingDouble(RuleComparator::getTabOrder)`), to simply be compatible with the specialized `double getTabOrder(Rule rule)` method. Instead, I get the error "*Cannot resolve method 'getTabOrder'*"

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe since there are multiple implementations of `getTabOrder`?  Try the direct method call, should be similar to `.comparingDouble(r-> getTabOrder(r))`

Comment: It works if I specify the Rule type on the generic property: ` .<Rule>comparingDouble(StampaRuleComparator::getTabOrder)`. But why it is needed?

Comment: @AndrewS, it either doesn't if the thenComparing methods are present. It looses the reference to Rule completely. To make it work with both formats, the generic type must the specified explicitly. Strange though.